# Detect when user put the app in background

Tags: android, service, background

My android app uses an SQLite database.
A service is triggered every weeks to update data. Once the service has downloaded the required data, it then writes data with writeData() into the database but I need the service to wait until the user is not using the app anymore.

So I have to call my writeData() function WHEN the app is put in background.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Override onBackPress in the MainActivity and intercept the HOME KEY pressed in every activity to send your service a background flag.

Answer (score 0):

u can make a singelton class and  whenever your app opens initialize this singelton
 so every time before calling the write data check whether your singelton is null or not if null execute the writedata method if no then the user is opening the app

Answer (score 0):

check this documentation about component callback http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a use case for the onPause() life cycle callback.